# Changing range in a lookup formula based upon a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large excel file with approximately 200 sheets with fields. Each sheet is a ranking of a subset of values which was output from an R program. There are 2 versions for about each entry. The subset data is not in the original sheet - only the name of the sheet, and the summary table i'm trying to build. I'd like to automatically determine which range (sheet) the lookup queries.

The Manual answer is to sort, filter create a lookup and consolidate the summary data, copy the formula, find replace the range reference, fill, repeat.  hopefully there is a solution rather than copy-pasting, editing, hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-think the data architecture. If possible, let the golden rule apply to have data in one sheet and reporting on other sheets.

Find a way to have all the 200 sheet's data in just one sheet. You may have to introduce a few additional columns to distinguish each row.

Then you can start building reports on all the data, using Pivot Tables, or more sophisticated tools like Power Pivot.

With the next to nothing info you provide about your data set it is hard to suggest more concrete advice.

Comment: Actually the most useful thing that would help my data set is a VBA script to place the name of the worksheet into a new column of data on my, then for all of the sheets to be merged into a single sheet in a new bookl.